# TextBox Password Char

Tags: wpf, textbox, passwords, controls, char

the textbox in Windows Forms used to have a PasswordChar property. In WPF there is an extra control for that: PasswordBox. This wouldn't be a problem but my application runs on an touchscreen only device. Unfortunately the password box does not support the on screen keyboard. I was wondering if there is a way of adding the password char feature to the standard textbox.

Comment: almost identical to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612757/how-do-i-change-the-on-screen-keyboard-for-a-passwordbox)

Comment: No, that has absolutely nothing to do with my problem. I'm talking about WPF on Windows and the other question is about Silverlight for Windows Phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6629237/107899) may provide you with what you need.

Comment: At first I tried to write my own control but that imposes some problems with caret position, character deletion and text selection. Therefore I used this answer in a slightly different form. I hide a textbox behind the passwordbox and focus the textbox when the passwordbox gets focused. The text property of the textbox is bound to the Password property of the password box. Its not very clean but it kind of works for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I made my way around this particular problem by creating two Properties for the Password content and binding both of them to the same Model value.  One of them (the visible UI Element) binds to Password.  The Get on this property of course then returns an array of characters for display.  The functions that must use the password text can use the PlainPassword Property.

Adding "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" to the Binding for the textbox causes the characters to appear in the text box as they are typed.

```
  public string Password
  {
     set
     {
        Model.Password = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Password");
     }
     get 
     {
        return new String('●', Model.Password.Length); 
     }
  }

  public string PlainPassword
  {
     set
     {
        Model.Password = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Password");
     }
     get { return Model.Password; }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way you can achieve this is to create your own control based on textbox.  Then just bind the actual text property to a property that returns your password character rather than the actual password.  Then you can pull the password as a dependency property (though I've heard this is rather insecure, which is why it is not a dependency property in the password box), or just a regular property and access it by passing the whole textbox object.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to obfuscate the password in a `TextBox` is to use the `Webdings` font.

```
txtInput.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Webdings");
```

This is not completely safe, but sufficient in most cases. Note that `Webdings` works better than `Wingdings`, because `Wingdings` does not cover the lower case letters and returns everything in upper case.

Answer (score 0):

helló!

im new here  but maybe i can help u. i find this -> can be work whit WPF and passwordbox

```
private void delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    if (pass_passbox.IsFocused == true)
        {
            pass_passbox.Password= "";
        }
    }
```

ofc u do this pass_passbox.Text if its textbox but when change WPF passwordbox u need to write can pass_passbox.Password and u can do changes from screen keyboard .

not fully tested but u can reset this way

and u can do select like this:

```
string Query = "Select * from [employeeinfo] where username='" + this.txt_user_name.Text + "' and password='" + this.pass_passbox.Password + "' ";
```

u can see this.pass_passbox.Password is the same at textbox this.pass_passbox.Text

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void txtBoxPassword_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //password view protection//
        txtBoxPassword.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
    }
```

That's a way to enable the DEFAULT character used for hiding the password from the system,if you wish to set your own password char just substitute the actual line inside the event function with the following:
     txtBoxPassword.PasswordChar='*'; //or any other character